# How to display an error on a field when the value of another field changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a WPF application with a dialog box that allows the user to edit the settings of an object.  I'm using MVVM for this dialog.  My view Model Object for this dialog implements the `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

One of the fields on the form is a `ComboBox` that is mapped to a property of the View Model object that is an enum.  There are other fields on the form whose validation logic depends upon the value of the field bound to the `ComboBox`.

Individually, when the values of the different fields are entered, they validate and the dialog displays the correct error status.  That is, when you create a new object and edit the form to specify values different from the defaults, the error state of each control is displayed properly.  My problem is that when you edit an existing object, and you change the selected value in the `ComboBox`, the value that may be specified in a field that appears further down the dialog may be invalid, but the error state is not being displayed.

Here's the code that runs when you change the selected value of the `ComboBox`:

```
    private void TypePicker_SelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e ) {
        IsDirty = true;
        MyCommands.SaveChanges.CanExecute( this, OkButton );
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

`MyCommands` is a class; the commands are static properties of that class.  IsDirty is a `bool DependencyProperty` belonging to the dialog.

How do I get the other fields to validate when I change the selected value in the `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this work.  It is more of a brute force technique but it works.

I added code to set the value of the `TextBox` controls for the dependent fields to their current value.  This raises the `TextChanged` event for these controls, which causes the properties associated with them to be revalidated and the error condition gets displayed.  For example,

```
private void TypePicker_SelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e ) {
    IsDirty = true;
    FirstDependentTextBox.Text = ViewModelObject.Property1;
    SecondDependentTextBox.Text = ViewModelObject.Property2;
    MyCommands.SaveChanges.CanExecute( this, OkButton );
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This works.  I'm not happy with it as it seems there should be a more elegant way to do the same thing, but it does work and it's what I'm using for now.